# iPhone 5 to iPhone 4 screen size

Tags: ios7, xcode5, screen, objective-c-blocks

I have made an app for the 4-inch iPhone and was wondering how I can make it also run on a 3.5 inch screen without it just cutting off part of the screen. I have read about auto layout but I'm not sure if my project is set up for it. My view controllers are set to landscape and 4 inch display.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can design a single screen  for all devices (iPhone or iPad) . 
I recommend watching the WWDC 2012 session [Introduction to Auto Layout for iOS and OS X.](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202)
If you do not want to use auto layout then you have  autoresizing masks, that described how a subview will resize or move when its superview is resized.

Refer to These tutorials

[Tutorial 1](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout/)

[Tutorial 2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[Tutorial 3](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)

[Tutorial 4](http://captechconsulting.com/blog/jack-cox/ios-7-tutorial-series-auto-layout-xcode-5)

Hope This Helps